# Display short time zone name using DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I have the following `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzzz");
```

I am using it to format a `ZonedDateTime` like this:

```
ZonedDateTime disableTime = Instant.now()
        .plus(Duration.ofDays(21))
        .atZone(ZoneId.ofOffset("UTC", ZoneOffset.ofHours(-5)));
System.out.println(DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.format(disableTime));
```

I would like this to ouput a formatted date string, like the following:

> 09/16/2015 at 01:15:45 PM EDT

But what is getting output is this:

> 09/16/2015 at 01:15:45 PM UTC-05:00

No matter whether I use `z`, `zz`, `zzz`, or `zzzz` in the pattern, it always gets output in the above format.

Is there a different way to create the `ZonedDateTime` that will give me the desired output, or am I doing something wrong in the pattern?

As per the `DateTimeFormatter` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns), `O` should be used to display the localized zone-offset, such as `UTC-05:00`, while `z` should be used to display the time-zone name, such as `Eastern Daylight Time`, or `EDT`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you use an anonymous UTC offset. Try with a named `ZoneId` instead

```
ZonedDateTime disableTime = Instant.now()
     .plus(Duration.ofDays(21))
     .atZone(ZoneId.of("Africa/Nairobi"));
```

prints ("*Ora dell'Africa orientale*" is italian localized names)

```
09/16/2015 at 09:34:44 PM Ora dell'Africa orientale
```

You can get a list of available names that should use to store and retrieve the preferences from the user with

```
Set<String> ids = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds();
```

Comment: I used `ZoneId.of("America/New_York")` and it gave me the desired result. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason why the java.time package does not recognize `ZoneId.ofOffset("UTC", ZoneOffset.ofHours(-5))` is equivalent to `ZoneId.of("America/New_York")`? Or are they not equivalent?

Comment: Ah, nevermind. It's because `ZoneId.ofOffset("UTC", ZoneOffset.ofHours(-5))` will always have a UTC-05:00 offset, while `ZoneId.of("America/New_York)` will alternate between UTC-05:00 and UTC-04:00, based on daylight savings time. So they are not equivalent. Makes sense now.

Comment: Sure. Also, one offset is used by 0, 1 or N named zones